# Is Elementary OS a good OS for Linux Newbies?

Tags: virtualbox

I am quite new to Linux, only having toyed around with Ubuntu and Elementary OS in VirtualBox before. Would Elementary OS be good for beginners like me?

I searched online a didn't find anything that answered my question.

Also, when I was toying around with Elementary OS in VirtualBox, the app store would not open and I couldn't install any applications using apt. Is this just a VBox error? (Please note that I was running a root when this error occurred. [i.e. using sudo su])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running a Live OS in virtual box rather than the installed version than you would experience the issues you are having. In that case I suggest you boot up the live version and install the OS. Reboot and you should be able to install apps.

To answer your subject, yes elementary is a relatively good linux OS for beginners. Based on Ubuntu 16.04 it's stable and reliable. Though not completely free of issues (as you can see from this StackExchange page). Some other great OSs for beginners are Solus, Mint, Ubuntu, etc.  Solus is relatively issue free and rock solid, while Ubuntu and Mint have very large online communities that are friendly to new users.

Comment: what do you mean by a live os, because i've never heard the term before.

Comment: Extract "Live OS is just an Operating System, like any other Operating System, the only difference being, ‘The whole Operating System is pre-installed the CD/Pen-drive’.
Yes! You don’t need to install Live OS. Insert the CD/Pen-drive, and use it. As simple as that. Finished with your work? Just eject the CD/Pen-drive. Live OS generally comes with Linux Kernels."  https://geekstarts.info/live-os/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the ability to write data, in his case, install apps, is dependent upon the environment in which the live OS is running. I've had luck on some usbs with varying degree based on the tool used to create it. I've never had luck on virtual box.

Comment: To confirm this I booted into the live environment and no new applications are available. The only apps listed in the appcenter are ones that are already installed that come with the live install. So, no, in a live environment you cannot install apps. This is likely what you are experiencing. Installing the OS on your VM will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is YES. Although it is easier for users that come from the Apple world you can get used to it without major difficulties. You will have a system: simple, elegant and with wonderful design.

I recommend you the article

> Best Linux Distributions For Beginners
>   Last updated June 11, 2017 By Aquil Roshan>

*published in It's Foss*

https://itsfoss.com/best-linux-beginners/

Where you can form an opinion about which distribution is more convenient for you.

As an elementary OS user I would like you to give it a try to elementary OS but I think you must know about all the options before choosing any distro.

I hope to see you here again. ;-)

Comment: what about drivers? How good is the driver support? Is it the same as Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, the theory is that if it works in Ubuntu should work in elementary which is almost always true. Try burning an image in DVD or USB stick. Change your BIOS priority boot options and see that everything works. If so you can proceed to install it. (That is a Live session as we discussed before)

Answer (score 0):

I am a relative noob to the entire Linux experience, pretty much diving in head first, watching TONS of tutorials and reading volumes of reviews and forum entries. i am a born distro-hopper i suppose. My point being, that i have tried many different beginner level distros, and my honest opinion is that Elelmentary OS is by far the most user friendly.  I continue to come back to it every time because it is so straight-forward, and when problems are encountered, the solution usually is achieved with minimal effort.

Great support forums and a friendly community as well.  *Hope you enjoy the discovery process as much as i have!*